# Apache 2 mpm-itk fails a setgid() call after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to port over a custom Apache setup from Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu 14.04 (and therefore Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4). All my config files are separately managed off of the package management system in `/etc/apache2-custom`.

We use mpm-itk. One of the things I am noticing that is different is that it is actually compiled as an extension this time, so I need to `LoadModule` it. I have this at the top of all my `LoadModule` directives.

```
LoadModule mpm_prefork_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so
LoadModule mpm_itk_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mpm_itk.so
```

All good, but when I visit a site which uses `AssignUserID group1 group1`, I get a 500 internal server error. Looking at my error.log:

```
(itkmpm: pid=29765 uid=33, gid=33) itk_post_perdir_config(): setgid(120208): Operation not permitted
```

To be clear, uid/gid=33 is www-data and the setgid() is going to group1. I read this as my request processes are running as an unprivileged user. Shouldn't they be root?

Some seem to be getting this problem too, but they all involve CGI:

- [Arch Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=195710)
- [Using mailman](http://lists.err.no/pipermail/mpm-itk/2015-January/000846.html)
- [Debian bugs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=734814)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case it was [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mpm-itk/+bug/1517214) which made mpm-itk unable to support uid's and gid's over 65535. There is a patch in the issue tracker which corrects the behavior.